# Solving an alphametic puzzle by eavesdropping

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, alphametic

I took part in a meeting of puzzle maniacs. I overheard a conversation between two persons.

A: Hey, solve this alphametic problem. LHS is a square of two-digit number and RHS is a four-digit number.

B: Does it contain some middle steps?

A: No. That's a whole. Can you solve it?

After some minutes, B asked.

B: The answer cannot be determined. If we know whether the number is odd or even, it could be unique.

A: Wait, please. Let me read again. Oh, sorry. The parity was mentioned in the problem.

A read the sentence about parity to B.

B: OK. That figures. If the parity was given reversely, we couldn't get the unique answer.

I did not see their problem. But, I could solve it just by eavesdropping.

What's the answer of this alphametic problem?

PS. The parity in the dialogue means whether the RHS number is odd or even.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is:

> $93^2 = 8649$

Reasoning:

> There are 3 possible puzzles matching the conversation:
>  $(AB)^2 = CDCB$, where AB can be 56, 45, 81 or 91
>  $(AB)^2 = CDDB$, where AB can be 46, 35, 65 or 85
>  $(AB)^2 = CDEA$, where AB can be 42, 48 or 93
>  If A said that the number is even, and B deduced the unique answer, then AB can be either 56 or 46, leaving "I" unable to solve it.
>  Therefore the number is odd, and the answer is $93^2 = 8649$.

Earlier answer (before the edit):

How about:

> Puzzle: $(AB)^2 = CDEA$
>  The solutions are: $42^2 = 1764$, $48^2 = 2304$, $93^2 = 8649$

For the parity part:

> If we know A is odd, AB is 93, otherwise its 42 or 48
>  If we know B is odd, AB is 93, otherwise its 42 or 48
>  If we know C is odd, AB is 42, otherwise its 48 or 93
>  If we know D is even, AB is 93, otherwise its 42 or 48
>  E must be even in this puzzle

However...

> We still can't deduce the answer of the alphametic problem, unless we heard the sentence about parity clearly. If we know which number/letter's parity is given, we can get the answer.

How I get the answer:

> I listed all the squares between 1000~9999. There are only 67 of them so its relatively easy to bruteforce. After listing the squares I looked for the potential puzzles with 3 solutions or more and find this.

Comment: The parity means that of the RHS number.

Comment: Get it, the answer is now updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how to prove its uniqueness, but here is a possible situation:

> Puzzle: $AB^2=CDCB$.
>  The solutions: $56^2=3136$, $81^2=6561$, $91^2=8281$, $45^2=2025$.
>  Unique if we know the numbers are even.

How I get this:

> Let the last digit be same (so my work will be easier) and list squares of two-digit integers ending with $1,5,6$.

Comment: Find some more possible situations.